# How to update a certain value inside this jackson JsonNode?

Tags: java, json, jackson

**TLDR**:
I want to update certain value of a JsonNode key `dependsOn` and return the result as a JsonNode. Currently I'm converting the value to a `String`, slicing the characters and then using `ObjectMapper` to convert the string back to `JsonNode`

I have a json object like shown below

```
{
    "name": "somename",
    "type": "sometype",
    "description": "some desc",
    "properties": {
        "path": "some path",
        
        "dependsOn": [
            "ABC:zzz","DEF:sdc","GHI:ere"
        ],
        
        "checkpoint": "some checkpoint",
        "format": "some format",
        "output": "some output",
        "table": "some table"
    }
}
```

I'm currently parsing the above json data and fetching the `dependsOn` as JsonNode element (as shown below)

```
JsonNode components = model.get("properties");
JsonNode dependsOn = components.get("dependsOn");
```

When I print `dependsOn` it looks like this `"["ABC:zzz","DEF:sdc","GHI:ere"]"`

My requirement was to `strip` everything after `:` from the `dependsOn` array

This below code helped me to convert the JsonNode to String and then strip `:whatever` then convert it back to JsonNode

```java
if (dependsOn != null && !dependsOn.isEmpty()) {
  String dependsOnString =
          components
                  .get("dependsOn")
                  .get(0)
                  .textValue()
                  .substring(
                          0,
                          (components.get("dependsOn").get(0).textValue().lastIndexOf(":") != -1)
                                  ? components.get("dependsOn").get(0).textValue().lastIndexOf(":")
                                  : components.get("dependsOn").get(0).textValue().length());
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  dependsOn = mapper.readTree("[\"" + dependsOnString + "\"]");
}
```

**Input:**

```
"["ABC:zzz","DEF:sdc","GHI:ere"]"
```

**Output**

```
"["ABC","DEF:sdc","GHI:ere"]"
```

Above code only strip the first element of the array I can loop and perform the same for rest of the elements though. But I have a couple of questions regarding whatever I'm trying to do

> Firstly, am I doing this in a right way or is there a simpler
> technique to do this? instead of converting it to string and then
> again to JsonNode..
>
> Next, I've only done this to the `first element of the array`
> and I want to loop through and do this for `all the elements of the array`. Is there a simpler solution to this instead of using a for/while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my usecase suggests my `dependsOn` value should not be overridden at node level, I had to convert the **JsonNode** to **String** and then used the regular expression matcher to replace `:xyz` with an empty string in each element then **convert it** back to **JsonNode**

```
String pattern = ":[a-zA-Z]+";
        String newDependsOn = dependsOn.toString().replaceAll(pattern, "");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        dependsOn = mapper.readTree(newDependsOn);
```

@Gautham's solution did work too but what I think is it was overriding at the root and the old value wasn't available anymore outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the `dependsOn` after casting it to `ArrayNode` and set value to it:

```java
ArrayNode array = ((ArrayNode) dependsOn);
List<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++) {
    newValues.add(array.get(i).asText().split(":")[0]);
}

array.removeAll();
newValues.forEach(array::add);
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want your original `dependsOn` to be updated then use:

```java
JsonNode copy = dependsOn.deepCopy();
// or you could invoke `deepCopy` on the `ArrayNode` as well
```

Now pass this `copy` object for slicing operation. So that the original json remains unchanged.

Comment: after this, will the final array of sliced values will be in dependsOn node ? or should I add ````dependsOn = array```` after this?

Comment: @Akhil, No `dependsOn` would already be updated. If you output `components` you could see the updated json

Comment: Yeah got it. Tested and works as expected "except" that my dependsOn should not be overridden like in the above code (ArrayNode casting is doing that) as I'm passing the ````dependsOn```` to different functions and it should not send the sliced content rather the previous data

Comment: @Akhil I think you haven't mentioned this use case in the question. Anyway, I have updated the answer. you could use `deepCopy` to avoid updating the original node.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, without convert to string and parse again to jsonNode

```
JsonNode prop = node.get("properties");
JsonNode arrayCopy = prop.get("dependsOn").deepCopy();
var array = ((ObjectNode)prop).putArray("dependsOn");
IntStream.range(0, arrayCopy.size())
    .forEach(index -> {
      String elem = arrayCopy.get(index).asText();
      String finalElem = elem.substring(0,elem.contains(":") ? elem.lastIndexOf(':') : elem.length());
      array.add(finalElem);
    });
```